# OCM JavaEE6 Certification exam - About integration (JMS or not)

Tags: java, jms

I am preparing for the Oracle JEE6 Architect Certification (1Z0-807). Sample questions can be found in the corresponding book as well as online. The sample questions seem reasonable, but for some of the provided answers seem plain wrong to me.

For example, a question I encountered in various places:

*Blue Berry Corporation, one of the biggest fruit traders in Canada, has the biggest competitor, Red Cherry Corporation. Blue Berry uses a web application that is developed by using java technologies, whereas Red Cherry’s web application uses non-Java technologies. Blue Berry plans to share business sensitive, transactional data between the two systems by integrating them in a loosely coupled manner. Which technology should be used to this?*

*A) JMS*
*B) JCA*
*C) XML over HTTPS*
*D)  RMI over IIOP*
*E)  JBI*

*Answer: A, C*

The Study Guide from Oracle Press does says clearly *JMS is not recommended for non-Java integration*. Therefore, answer *A)* would be wrong.

What is your take on that? Any insights from people who passed the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure two answers are required? I saw this question somewhere and it needed only one answer, which was given as JCA. These questions are mostly incorrect, not sure who answers them

I would have just said C. You are right about JMS not being recommended but its certainly possible. B, no, JCA caused tight coupling and is recommended for legacy EIS. D no, tight coupling. E not sure im assuming no

Comment: So if i had to pick 2 i would say A and C. If the pick is only 1 i would say C

Answer (score 0):

Reading the book OCM Java EE 6 - Enterprise Architect Exam Guide, I've found that:
- JMS is not recommended for non-Java integration
- JCA is tight coupling between EIS and application

So, JMS and JCA are not good choices.

XML over HTTPS, regardless the fact that It "uses standards to address QoS requirementes for security and reliability", it needs to use JTA for transaction management.

JBI, which is a specification that "defines a standard means for assembling integration components" has loosely couple as one of its goals. Furthermore, it provides support for transactions. So, I think that the best answer for this question is JBI.

What do you think?